# Syntax Error or Engine Error?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone I'm trying to create a page to create a db from a php page. But at the time of running the page and then creating the Mysql database the browser returns me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; to the right to use the new
>   version of the server.

I put in the code as MyISAM engine and not MariaDB (or AIR) so I do not understand the problem because I checked from the control panel of XAMPP for scruple and the version I still use has among the MyISAM engines.

I copy the code I used thanks to all those who want to give me a hand.

```
 < $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'pizzaballa') or die
 ('Non è possibile connettersi. Controllare i parametri di
 connessione.');


 $query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS moviesite';
 mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

 mysql_select_db('moviesite', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

 $query = 'CREATE TABLE movie ( movie_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCRMENT, movie_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, movie_type TINYINT
 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, movie_year SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 movie_leadactor INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, movie_director
 INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

 PRIMARY KEY (movie_id), KEY movie_type (movie_type, movie_year) )
 ENGINE=MyISAM'; mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

 $query = 'CREATE TABLE movietype ( movietype_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT
 NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, movietype_label VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY
 KEY (movietype_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM'; mysql_query($query, $db) or die
 (mysql_error($db));

 $query = 'CREATE TABLE people ( people_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT, people_fullname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, people_isactor
 TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, people_isdirector TYNIINT(1)
 UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

 PRIMARY KEY (people_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM'; mysql_query($query, $db) or
 die (mysql_error($db));

 echo 'Database movie creato correttamente!';
```

Comment: add  also the exact error message you get  ..

Comment: 1.`mysql_*` is deprecated library, use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.2. use `not exist clause` in your `CREATE TABLE` query

Comment: Thanks i change my code changind myql to mysqli_ and add if nott exist in to CREATE TABLE but now i have a sintax error about 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Apprendo\db_ch03-1.php on line 12

Comment: So, look at line 12 and see if param 1 is a string - you are probably passing an INT. As I say in my answer, a debugger will let you examine that variable and immediately see the problem, without having to wait for us to answer.

Comment: Or, at least tell us which one is line 12

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE people ( people_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT, people_fullname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, people_isactor
 TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, people_isdirector TYNIINT(1)
 UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (people_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

**TYNIINT** is not a valid column type. This should be corrected to **TINYINT**.

The complete error message *should* give you a rough idea on where the error comes from. If not, pasting your queries into any SQL editor with syntax coloring may also prove useful.

Comment: Thanks i change the TINYINT error and use mysqli_ but now i recive these error message Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given. I look on the line of error message but i have declare mysqli_query($query, $db) or die (mysqli_error($db));

Comment: There are several online SQL syntax checkers, such as [this one](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) (it's not the only one - Google)

Answer (score 0):

"You have an error in your SQL syntax;" - that's clear enough. One of those `mysql_query` statements has en error in the SQL.

1) always wrap such code in `try` & hellip; `catch`. Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

2) use an IDE (such as[Eclipse]9https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), but there are others), and learn to use the debugger. It is the most powerful tool that you have. You can set a breakpoint, let the code run and it will stop there. You can then examine variables and the call stack, and step through your code, line by line, until you code to the error.

these two things will answer not just this question, but many more which you might have asked us in the future, but will now be able to answer yourself.

Comment: I'm already use an IDE Dreamweaver and i don't see error warning in debugging....

Comment: I haven't used Dremweaver for about 20 years, but I doubt if it allows one to debug PHP (in fact, back then it had no PHP support). If it does, set breakpoints & step through your code, lien by line. If it does not support that, use an IDE that does (such as [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)